# How to give src to image in <a> tag in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am converting Html Template to WordPress, I have done 90% of the work.

In my Template, I have some `<a>` which are href to the images path as

```
<a href="img/elements/g7.jpg" class="img-pop-up">
```

Now i want to link this  path in wordpress using any funtion,like i have done for img tag as

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="">
```

May you help me,how can i give the path to image using `<a>`tag.

Comment: are you using a child theme ? `<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="">`

Comment: no i am not using the child theme

Comment: what;s the main problem? tell us clearly.

Comment: i want to give the path to images which are save in folder, using the a tag,i don't know how to give them in wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get an image in Wordpress.

---

**1)** If you image is the thumbnail image of the page or post, you can simply use echo of `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="">
```

---

**2)** If your image is in the media library, you can use the function `wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr );`. You must know the image ID.

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(300, array('800', '600'), "", array("class" => "image")); ?>
```

**300** is the ID of the image in the library (you can discover it looking at the number in the url when opening the image there).
**800** and 600 is the size.
An attribute was added: `class="image"`.

By default, it will output this:

```
<img width="700" height="466" src="example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/image.png" class="image attachment-700x600 size-700x600" alt="" srcset="example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/image.png 800w, example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/image-png-1-300x200.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 700px) 100vw, 700px">
```

---

**3**) If you want the image from media library as well, but just the url, you can use `wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id )` function. Like this:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url(1286); ?>
```

**4**) If you image is in a custom field, created using the [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin, for example. Then, you call `the_field` using like this:

```
<?php the_field('image_field_name'); ?>
```

---

**5)** If the image is not in the media library, but in the theme folder, you can use the `get_stylesheet_directory()` to find the theme folder and render the image. For example, if the image is inside the theme folder, inside another folder called img.

```
<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory().'/img/image.png'; ?>
```

Comment: *Some more examples* if it is not in the media library, but in the theme folder f.x - then you can `echo get_stylesheet_directory().'/img/logo.png';`